# In Flutter, command not found 'flutter' , how can use bloc library?

Tags: flutter, bloc

For using bloc library, set the path again and again but I couldn't solve the problem 'command not found flutter', Is there any resolvation to use bloc without terminal?

Comment: Please provide more information and some example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set your flutter environment path yet.

**For Windows:**
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

**For Mac:**
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#get-sdk

Answer (score -1):

In your android studio go to your pubspec.yaml file in the root directory and under the dependencies add bloc as follows

```
dependencies:
  bloc: ^8.1.0
```

Then there will be an option to run pub get inside android studio
[Pub get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK6OL.png)

Or you can open up the terminal from inside android studio and run your commands there